# Angular Material - All acceptable arguments for `mat-palette()`

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-theming

In the Angular Material custom theming documentation, we are setting the primary color as indigo like this:

```
$candy-app-primary: mat-palette($mat-indigo);
```

Where can i refer all acceptable arguments for the `mat-palette()` function?
I wanted to know all possible color names like we have `$mat-indigo`in the above example. Couldn't find it in the documentation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find in [the source file](https://github.com/angular/material/blob/master/src/core/services/theming/theme.palette.js) of angular material, all the predefined colors.

And

If you want a custom theme, you can use color generator such as [mcg.mbitson.com](http://mcg.mbitson.com)

Comment: 404 for your source